# If $\gcd(a,n)=1$, and $x^k\equiv a\bmod n$, then $\gcd(x,n)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am sure that it's very clear but I don't get it:

Given the following: $\gcd(a,n)=1$; $\gcd(k, \phi(n))=1$; $x^k\equiv a \bmod n$.

Why $\gcd(x,n)=1$?

(I need to use it in proof I got)

Answer (score 1):

For any $x$ and $y$, it is true that $\gcd(x,n)\mid \gcd(xy,n)$. 
Therefore, $\gcd(x,n)$ divides $\gcd(x^k,n)$.

If $y\equiv z\bmod n$, then $\gcd(y,n)=\gcd(z,n)$.
Therefore, $\gcd(x^k,n)=\gcd(a,n)=1$.

Therefore, $\gcd(x,n)$ divides $1$, and therefore it must be $1$.

(The statement that $\gcd(k,\phi(n))=1$ is unnecessary.)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose to the contrary that $x$ and $k$ are not relatively prime. Then there is some prime $p$ that divides $x$ and $n$.

From $x^k \equiv a\pmod{n}$ we conclude, unless $k=0$, that $p$ divides $a$, contradicting the fact that $\gcd(a,n)=1$.

For $k=0$ we can find a counterexample. Let $n=2$, $a=1$, and $x=2$.

Comment: I forgot to mention: a,k,n are natural numbers. thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, I was assuming integers, with $k\ge 0$.